# How to format time with decimal places with excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that takes a time value in seconds (decimal) and converts it to mm:ss.00 format (two decimal places.) The closest I've come is this:

```
Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
```

Which results in:

```
00:01.2
```

I can't figure out why it's not showing the second decimal place.

Format() doesn't work either:

```
Format((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
```

result:

```
12:01.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the above in VBA and for `Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")` I get `00:01.23`  and for `Format((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")`, I get `12:01.00`

If you are writing it to an Excel cell then do this

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
"'" & Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
```

or

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
"'" & Format((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
```

Alternatively, you can also use this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "mm:ss.00"
    .Value = Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
End With
```

or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "mm:ss.00"
    .Value = Format((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. What's the meaning of `_"'" &` ?

Comment: It's for line continuation. I can also write it like this `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "'" & Application.Text((1.23 / 86400), "mm:ss.00")`

Answer (score 1):

We have found that the `Format()` VBA function does not support decimal places after the second mm:ss.00. Not mentioned in the official doc.

So, instead of using the `Format()` function, we called the worksheet function `TEXT()` within the VBA code:

```
TeamTime(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(thisCell, "mm:ss.00")
```